# How to loop through multiple aliases of the same route?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my App I have a dashboard page with 2 Charts. Each chart uses a different configuration but the same API end-point. I would like to check if the payload for each end point is correct:

```js
cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/api/v1/company/*/statistics/charts/data?cache_buster=*`,
}).as('chartData');
```

I have this route intercept which is matched twice.

I can do this:

```js
cy.wait('@chartData').then((data: any) => {
    expect(data.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);
    expect(data.request.body.document_types[0]).to.eq('receipt');
    expect(data.request.body.document_types[1]).to.eq('invoice');

    expect(data.request.body.filters[0].comparison_operator).to.eq('==');
    expect(data.request.body.filters[0].field).to.eq('purchase_date');
    expect(data.request.body.filters[0].type).to.eq('field_value');
    expect(data.request.body.filters[0].value).to.eq('this_year');
});
```

Which works but I cannot check the values of the second match.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two responses to the same endpoint, set up **one intercept** with **one alias** and wait twice.

Use a common check function, and branch the asserts depending on the request or response properties.

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/api/v1/company/*/statistics/charts/data?cache_buster=*`,
}).as('chartData')

cy.visit('/dashboard')


const checkChartData = (dvata) => {
  expect(data.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);

  const documentType = data.request.bodydocument_type

  expect(documentType).to.be.oneOf(['receipt', 'invoice'])

  // asserts dependent on type
  if (documentType === 'invoice') {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}

cy.wait('@chartData').then(checkChartData)
cy.wait('@chartData').then(checkChartData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `cy.get('@chartData.all')` to access all the intercepts at a given point in your test. NOTE: this will not wait for any intercepts only retrieve the number of matching intercepts and cy.wait('@chartData') will only wait for the first matching request.

```js
cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/api/v1/company/*/statistics/charts/data?cache_buster=*`,
}).as('chartData');

// action to trigger 1st and 2nd request
cy.wait('@chartData1') // only waits on first matching, regardless if 2nd occurs
```

So you can either take this approach and try to use `cy.get('@chartData.all')` at an appropriate time in your test to get the second matching intercept or you can create another intercept with matching params and a unique alias for the 2nd matching.

```js
cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/api/v1/company/*/statistics/charts/data?cache_buster=*`,
}).as('chartData');

// action to trigger 1st request
cy.wait('@chartData1') 

// some other actions in test

cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/api/v1/company/*/statistics/charts/data?cache_buster=*`,
}).as('chartData2');

// action to trigger 2nd request
cy.wait('@chartData2')
```